# JQuery não pega valor do input

Tags: jquery, seletores

```js
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
    console.log($('#prescricao[qtd][1]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="prescricao" id="prescricao[qtd][1]" class="form-control input-md prescricao" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" tabindex="2"/>

<button name="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Cadastrar</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tens de escapar `[]` dentro da string pois ela vai ser interpretada como seletor CSS e em seletores `[]` significa seletor de atributo no HTML. Assim com `\\`antes de cada `[]` já vai dar.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
  console.log($('#prescricao\\[qtd\\]\\[1\\]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="prescricao" id="prescricao[qtd][1]" class="form-control input-md prescricao" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" tabindex="2" />

<button name="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Cadastrar</button>
```